# How to make a wit.ai bot send the first message ?

Tags: chatbot, wit.ai

While adding a story, the first message always starts with the user. Is there any way to make the bot send the first message ?

Answer (score 0):

wit.ai is an nlp-based text processor. It has to receive an input to give an output.
To initiate the message, initiate from whatever application you have developed your bot(which you have integrated with wit.ai) with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use predefined "greeting text " for welcoming users.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "setting_type":"greeting",
  "greeting":{
    "text":"Timeless apparel for the masses."
  }
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settings?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/thread-settings/greeting-text